# await { ... } in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a bunch of async functions, that I always or nearly always want to call synchronously.  So we all know the pattern

```
async function somethingcool() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "Cool Thing");
  });
}    
const coolthing = await somethingcool();
console.log(coolthing);
```

But I have this cool module called manycooolthings which offers many cool things, all via async functions that I always or nearly always want to await on.

```
import * as cool from 'manycoolthings';
await cool.updateCoolThings();
const coolThing = await cool.aCoolThing();
const anohtherCoolThing = await cool.anotherCoolThing();
const rus = await cool.coolThingsAreUs();
await cool.sendCoolThings();
await cool.postCoolThing(myCoolThing);
await cool.moreCoolThings();
const thingsThatAreCool = await cool.getThingsThatAreCool();
```

Extremely contrived and silly example, to illustrate the point. I do have a genuine use case, a set of tests based on puppeteer where most functions are async and they almost always want to be awaited on.

There must be a better way to avoid all the await pollution of our JavaScript code.

It would be great if could do something like

```
import * as cool from 'manycoolthings';
await {
  cool.updateCoolThings();
  const coolThing = cool.aCoolThing();
  const anotherCoolThing = cool.anotherCoolThing();
  const rus = cool.coolThingsAreUs();
  cool.sendCoolThings();
  cool.postCoolThing(myCoolThing);
  cool.moreCoolThings();
  const thingsThatAreCool = cool.getThingsThatAreCool();
}
```

Or even just

```
import * as cool from 'manycoolthings';
cool.updateCoolThings();
const coolThing = cool.aCoolThing();
const anotherCoolThing = cool.anotherCoolThing();
const rus = cool.coolThingsAreUs();
cool.sendCoolThings();
cool.postCoolThing(myCoolThing);
cool.moreCoolThings();
const thingsThatAreCool = cool.getThingsThatAreCool();
```

without having to worry if the method being called is async or not, because it's defined as an auto await function or something.

Comment: There are many alternative ways of writing this (strange) list of calls, none clearer and simpler than just putting `await` in front of the promise returning functions.

Comment: The first options looks a bit ambiguous to me. Every line will be awaited, or every line will run async and when all finish the flow will proceed?

Comment: I don't think such thing exists, but consider this: before `await`, to run async calls consecutively you'd be forced to chain/nest `then`s or worse. So code with await looks __very__ good in comparison :)

Comment: You could also wrap the functions to put the returned promises in a promise queue : you would just have to add one await for this queue (the wrapping could be done in a generic way)

Answer (score 3):

If you're unhappy with multiple `await`s or `then`s, you can make a little "sequence" helper:

```
let _seq = async fns => fns.reduce((p, f) => p.then(f), Promise.resolve(null))
```

and use it like this:

```
result = await seq(
  _ => cool.updateCoolThings(),
  _ => _.aCoolThing(),
  _ => _.anotherCoolThing(),
  _ => _.coolThingsAreUs(),
)
```

which is almost your snippet #2.